# SQL Server 12 Instance / server name change

Tags: sql-server-2012

I created a sql server instance and the name show up differently in test and prod.  How can i change the prod name to not have the names repeating ?

Prod :

select @@servername
EHCPSQL12\EHCPSQL12

select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename
EHCPSQL12\EHCPSQL12\EHCPSQL12

Test :

select @@servername
EHCXSQL12

select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename
EHCXSQL12\MSSQLSERVER

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of a named instance

```
sp_dropserver 'Server Name\old_Instance_name'
go
sp_addserver 'ServerName\New Instance Name','local'
go
```

Verify sql server instance configuration by running below queries

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

Restart the SQL Server Services.

```
net stop MSSQLServer
net start MSSQLServer
```

Comment: I tried but it still stays like EHCPSQL12\EHCPSQL12, why is it showing up twice and thrice ?

Comment: Sounds like you installed it as a named instance when you wanted a default instance. Try this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026/sql-server-convert-a-named-instance-to-default-instance

Comment: @user1918074 A default instance will return ServerName\MSSQLSERVER for SELECT @@servername + '\' + @@servicename.